# Supply Class object as a generic argument

Tags: java, generics

Is there a way to supply a object of `Class` as an argument to a generic method?

For example, I have a method:

```
public <T> Queue <T> getSomething (...)
```

And I have an object of `Class`, such as

```
Class<?> key = ...
```

Is there a way I can supply the `key` as the generic argument for the `getSomething(...)` method? A pseudo-coded example would be:

```
Queue<key> queue = object.<key>getSomething(...)
```

Comment: whyyyy??? what is the advantage of using object here? you can simply use ClassType

Comment: I have a collection of objects of class `Class<?>` and I want to iterate through the collection and make a new Queue with elements of the same type as in the collection. For example, the collection contains `Integer.class`, `Object.class`, etc., I want the Queues to be of `Queue<Integer>`, `Queue<Object>`, respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a class object into a method declared like this:

```
public <T> Queue<T> getSomething( Class<T> type, ... ) { ... }
```

Comment: I have already done so, but the issue is: I want the queue returned to have elements of the same type as `key`. So, if for example, `key` is `Class<Integer>`, the queue should have elements of `Integer`. I'm trying to do this so that I can loop through a collection of `Class<?>` objects and obtain a Queue with elements of that class within each iteration.

Comment: The declaration above shows how you declare the return type. How you generate the contents seems like a separate question. Are you looking to filter or convert the elements of the collection? What do you have so far?

Comment: I have a collection of objects of class `Class<?>` and I want to iterate through the collection and make a new Queue with elements of the same type as in the collection. For example, the collection contains `Integer.class`, `Object.class`, etc., I want the Queues to be of `Queue<Integer>`, `Queue<Object>`, respectively. In essence, I want the queue to contain elements of the type `?` in the `Class<?>`.

Comment: You can use Class.isAssignableFrom() with the parameter and each collection member's getClass().

Comment: Thank you for the help: I was able to use your suggestion and come up something like the following: `Queue<? extends Question> queue = obj.getSomething(clazz, ...);` and treated each queue as if it just held `Object`s (or something `extend`ed from `Object`). Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this, because it would be useless.

Generics type parameters is purely a compile-time type-checking facility. Therefore, what would be the point of a type parameter that is not known at compile time? You would not be able to say anything about it, and you would not be able to do anything with it.

Comment: G'day, I don't think it can be useful; however I doubt that you can use it with generics because each Return type needs to be declared as a _child_ of the generic.  You might as well write some lame (and easy) boilerplate.  One useful use-case is to check declarative inputs such as a JavaFX node a plugin-type, an interface-type, or database construct  against your Business Requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as an argument, like any other argument

```
Class<T> tClass = ...
Queue<T> queue = object.getSomething(tClass, ...);
```